# Reference request: foliations

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, poisson-geometry

I am looking for a gentle introduction to foliations for smooth manifolds, but I have a hard time finding a textbook explaining this notion. Wikipedia's links are also to articles. Is there any textbook/set of lecture notes which can get me started on foliations?

Comment: Introduction to foliations and Lie groupoids published by Cambridge should be a good place to start.